# Convert HDC to 32bit bitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap, gdi

I am working with a DirectX application which occasionally renders to child windows and I need to access the raw bytes of the rendered image from the HDC of that child window. When I Bitblt from one child window to another window of my own making I get the desired image so I know it is there.

Any ideas on how I should go about this? The image format also has to be 32bit BGRA.

Thanks

Comment: The question is, can those examples output a 32bit BGRA image format?

Comment: Well, I guess you'll never get the alpha because by then it will have been multiplied out. Also if the child window is obscured, you may not get everything. Better to re-render to an offscreen render target and get the data from that.